# Vote to reopen: What are the military pros and cons of a low gravity world vs a high gravity one?

Tags: support, close-reasons, vote-to-close

I would like to have this question un-held:

[What are the military pros and cons of a low gravity world vs a high gravity one?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/109340/what-are-the-military-pros-and-cons-of-a-low-gravity-world-vs-a-high-gravity-one)

For context, these two questions were originally just the one question that is now on hold:

[What are the military pros and cons of a low gravity world vs a high gravity one?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/109340/what-are-the-military-pros-and-cons-of-a-low-gravity-world-vs-a-high-gravity-one)

[What are the economic pros and cons of colonizing a low gravity world vs a high gravity one?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/109345/what-are-the-economic-pros-and-cons-of-colonizing-a-low-gravity-world-vs-a-high/109359#109359)

After a request that the original be split because it was too broad, I agreed, and thus split it roughly in half, into the two linked above. Part of why I am posting this here on Meta, is because several of the close votes were already in place *before* the question split even occurred. So I would like to put it before the community to decide if it should be reopened. They are both very similar questions, but are not duplicates. They ask two distinctly different questions.

Answer (score 2):

In general, please don't come to Meta with a request to un-hold a question. There is a review queue, and many of the same people who will see the meta post will already have seen it in the review queue (for example, like I did). But this is your first post on Meta, so lets give you the benefit of the doubt.

I think the question is still too broad. The bottom line for me, and keep in mind everyone will have their own metric for what the limit of 'too broad' is, is whether or not a question can be reasonably answered in 2,000 characters. I know its a kind of arbitrary limit, but in my experience, a good answer rarely needs to be that long.

So getting to the pros and cons of gravity levels, there is simply a lot to discuss. Even just from a military point of view, gravity affects many things. For space battles, it affects the density of the atmosphere, the speed of orbits, the distance from the planet of geostationary orbits. From the ground it affects the terrain by erosion, the composition and density of the atmosphere again, the ability of low gravity troops to survive, the viability of projectile vs energy weapons, etc.

When I review a question (in 15 sec or so, mind you) I total that up and think if how much I could write. When I looked at your question, I thought it was too much to write, so I rejected the re-open.

My advice to you going forward is to get even more specific. But also, please be sure you are looking around the site for other answers. There are questions about low gravity [vehicles](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/107023/would-trams-be-workable-on-a-low-gravity-world), [buildings](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/58418/skyscrapers-on-low-gravity-planets), [storms](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/28115/storms-on-a-low-gravity-planet), [the human body](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3781/how-would-the-human-body-develop-under-a-different-gravity), and many more. These should give you better idea of the scope of the question you should be asking.

Hope that helps.

Comment: If this is not the proper channel to do so then I apologize, but I was instructed to do so by this answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question

Comment: @Raznarok If you really don't understand why a question is closed, then it is appropriate to come to Meta. However, for every good faith "why is this closed" post on Meta, we (at Worldbuilding, at least) get 2 angry trolls, so I try to discourage it as a general rule. But more to the point, hopefully I have answered your question as to why the question was closed, from one of the close voters.

Comment: It's an aside, but gravity doesn't affect the density of the atmosphere per se. Earth has 1 g surface gravity and 1.01 bar surface atmospheric pressure (international standard atmosphere is 1013.25 hPa or 1.01325 bar); Venus has 0.904 g and 92 bar; Mars has 0.376 g and 0.006 bar; Titan has 0.14 g and just under 1.5 bar; and those are just rocky bodies within our solar system. Gravity *can* affect a body's ability to retain an atmosphere, and by consequence its composition, but it's far from the only factor that does and beyond a minimum level is nowhere near the dominant factor.